# Problem statistics of user visits to the site

Tags: php

There is a task to establish simple statistics of user visits to the site by adding an entry to the database.

But I encountered such a problem that with each page reload, writing to the table is performed again and again. In my project i'm using `ORM RedBeanPHP`

```
$_SESSION['visitors'] = array(
        $counter_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        $counter_date = date('Y-m-d'),
        $counter_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        $counter_views = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        $count = \R::count('counter_visitors'),
    );
    if (!empty($_SERVER)){
        \R::exec("INSERT INTO `counter_visitors` ( `ip`, `browser`, `date`, `views`) VALUES ('$counter_ip', '$counter_browser', '$counter_date', '$counter_views')");
        unset($_SESSION['visitors']);
        die;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent the SQL Injection using prepared statements and set ip as primary key and use insert update as below:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO counter_visitors (ip, browser, date, views) VALUES( ?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE browser= ?, date=?, views=?");
```

This will insert a row if the ip doesn't exists in table counter_visitors and update date, views and browser if ip exists

Comment: so easy as i think ty so much